# Does nexus repository duplicate binaries that're help in different repositories and have same digest?

Tags: nexus, binaryfiles, docker-repository

I have a bit confusion with regards binaries storage in Nexus. If I have only one blob store, and have multiple repos that use it, does duplication happens for binaries that have the same digest/hash?

For example: a docker image `alpine:latest`, is pushed to both `repo1` and `repo2` in Nexus which use the same blob store, is this image stored twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is stored twice if you push it to two seperate repositories.  This is true of any format.

Source: NXRM Experience and Sonatype Contributor

Comment: Thank you. I have actually tested this but kinda was hoping I am wrong. Since Jfrog has `checksum based storage`, I thought this would be the case in Nexus as well